# How to find the index corresponding to an array in another array? (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

There are 2 arrays `A` and `B`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])
B = np.array([2,5,2,1,1,6])
```

If the element in `A` exists in `B`, output their index in `B`. The ideal output `C` is：

```
C = np.array([3,4,0,2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a bit ugly, this should work. You want to use `np.where` and `np.concatenate`. I'm using a placeholder list to store values and recombine, there may be a smoother method, but this should do the trick until the further reading of the docs may provide a better solution.

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([1,2,3,4])
    B = np.array([2,5,2,1,1,6])
    
    preC= []
    for i in A:
        if len(np.where(B == i)[0]) > 0:
            preC.append(np.where(B == i)[0])
    C = np.concatenate(preC)
    
    print(C)
```